# Sum content of list which has the same content

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

I have a sortedList from type "Details" which has the following content:

```
[0]=Details test0: 28.01.2020
[0]=Details test1: 1234
[0]=Details test2: abcd
[0]=Details test3: 1
[0]=Details test4: 20.6
[0]=Details test5: 20.20

[1]=Details test0: 28.01.2020
[1]=Details test1: 1234
[1]=Details test2: abcd
[1]=Details test3: 1
[1]=Details test4: 20.6
[1]=Details test5: 20.20

[2]=Details test0: 29.01.2020
[2]=Details test1: 1234
[2]=Details test2: abcd
[2]=Details test3: 1
[2]=Details test4: 20.7
[2]=Details test5: 20.20
```

Now the sorted list returns all this objects but I want to sum up all with the same test0,test1,test2 and sum test3,test4 and test5 (test3+test3, test4+test4 and test5+test5):

```
[0]=Details test0: 28.01.2020
[0]=Details test1: 1234
[0]=Details test2: abcd
[0]=Details test3: 2
[0]=Details test4: 41.2
[0]=Details test2: 40.40

[1]=Details test0: 29.01.2020
[1]=Details test1: 1234
[1]=Details test2: abcd
[1]=Details test3: 1
[1]=Details test4: 2.7
[1]=Details test5: 20.20
```

I'm not sure if `list.stream().filter` is the best option for this problem. Any ideas?
two methods that should find all test0 duplicates:

```
    public static List<Detail> getDuplicates(final List<Detail> list) {
    return getDuplicatesMap(list).values()
        .stream()
        .filter(duplicates -> duplicates.size() > 1)
        .flatMap(Collection::stream)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

private static Map<String, List<Details>> getDuplicatesMap(List<Details> list) {
    return list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Details::test0));
}
```

Comment: can you show us some code please

Comment: Additionally, please explain what 'sum up' means for (for example): 28.01.2020 + 29.01.2020?  abcd + abcd?  20:38 + 20.6?

Comment: Name your variables with meaningful names please, It's hard to understand what are they

Comment: `[2]=Details test4: 20:38` is this data in your input correct? How do you plan to add these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is merging duplicate entries based on a few attributes and not just identifying the duplicates. Using `Collectors.toMap` with a `mergeFunction` should help you resolve this.

```
public static List<Details> getDuplicates(final List<Details> list) {
    return new ArrayList<>(list.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(dtl -> 
                            Arrays.asList(dtl.getTest0(), dtl.getTest1(), dtl.getTest2()), 
                    Function.identity(), Details::mergeDuplicates))
            .values());
}
```

where the merge function is assumed to be using type-specific `Number`s that can be added as in:

```
static Details mergeDuplicates(Details a, Details b) {
    return new Details(a.getTest0(), a.getTest1(), a.getTest2(),
            a.getTest3() + b.getTest3(), a.getTest4() + b.getTest4(), a.getTest5() + b.getTest5());
}
```

Comment: mergeDuplicates will not work because it needs two arguments.

Comment: @tamaramaria Which two arguments are you talking about? Did you mean two `Details` object? that's why it's used in the `toMap` represented using method reference.

Comment: `collectors.toMap(...,Details::mergeDuplicates)` will not work because it need two arguments.

Comment: @tamaramaria which are inferred based on the method reference, its pretty much same as read `(a,b) -> Details.mergeDuplicates(a,b)`

Comment: but my compiler throws an error at `Collectors.toMap(dtl -> 
                            Arrays.asList(dtl.getTest0(), dtl.getTest1(), dtl.getTest2()), 
                    Function.identity(), Details::mergeDuplicates)` am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @tamaramaria what error does it throw? notice the use of `values` only form the map that too wrapped by `new ArrayList<>()` for conversion.

Comment: `the method groupingBy<Function<? superT,? extendsK>) in the type Collectors is not applicable for the arguemnts (Details::mergeDuplicates)`

Comment: @tamaramaria If you notice, in my answer, there is no use of `groupingBy`. I have used `Collectors.toMap` instead to collect.

Answer (score 0):

Well, until we know what 'sum the properties' means, all I can do is give you a quick example of how to sum things sharing the same 'test number'.

```
final List<Details> detailses = ...; // Whatever you currently have.

detailses.stream()

        // Group by 'test number'.
        // This will return a Map<Integer, List<Details>>
        // The key is the test number, and the List contains all matching Details
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Details::getTestNumber))

        // Stream over the entries of this grouped map
        .entrySet().stream()

        // And collect it to another Map
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
            Map.Entry::getKey, // Keys stay the same

            // Values are mapped to the 'sum' of the properties...
            // However you choose to define that
            entry -> entry.getValue().stream()
                    .map(Details::getProperty)
                    .collect(/* Define summing the property here ... */)
        ));
```

This will result in a `Map<Integer, ?>` where the keys are the test numbers, and the values are the 'sum' of all the properties for `Details` with that test number.